# How to present data in two columns?

Tags: graph, count, character, letter

I have the following data where the columns in "Device Problem" and "Patient Problem" are interconnected. I am interested in showing how the number of a device problem of specific category (e.g., fire, mechanical problem etc.) is affected by a specific number of patient problem (burn, tissue damage etc.,) and visa versa. Do you have any recommendations? :)

[image]

Expected the request/question would be sent into the forum